# UIRefreshControl Inside of UITableView Causing App to Freeze on Rotation - iOS 6+

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

Ok StackOverflow People...I've got a very interesting problem that I've been trying to solve for days and can't figure out so I need some major help. This will most likely be a very lengthy description but please bear with me and thank you deeply in advance for reading all of this because the more words I have, the clearer I can describe the full picture to you all. I will do my absolute best to be as terse and coherent as I can possibly be. Please let me know wherever I fall short.

---

Here's the context of my problem: I'm using Storyboards for my iOS app and for a particular nav tab in my app, I had to create two separate scenes for both the Portrait and Landscape orientations. The reason for doing this (instead of say, using Autolayout), is because within this said tab, there are visual elements (table views, web views, etc.) that are laid out differently depending on the orientation and it was a lot easier to create a separate orientation scene to handle this change in the UI instead of doing it programmatically -- (it's also just a lot easier to understand and cleaner code-wise). So the take away to keep in mind from all of this is that these two separate Portrait and Landscape scenes represent the SAME TAB in my app. (Side Note: these scenes were made in the IB of course)

Now the visual elements that I mentioned in the UI earlier -- going deeper, they are all containers for different `UIViewControllers`. I sandboxed everything in the app and pretty much have a 1-to-1 relationship for all things so these containers will map to my subclassed `UIViewControllers` that I've created for their specific purposes -- but it's here that the first caveat of my problem arises. Here's a practical example for a clearer picture, I have one `UIViewController` that contains a `UITableView` called `MXSAnnouncementsViewController` and this same view controller exists in both the Landscape and Portrait scenes. I did not create an explicit Portrait or Landscape VERSION of that view controller but instead, have the controller keep track of two `IBOutlet` properties (`tableViewLandscape` and `tableViewPortrait`) that point to the orientation-specific `UITableViews` -- and this approach works perfectly fine. Moreover in my `MXSAnnouncementsViewController`, I have a local property called `tableView` that abstracts the orientation-specific table views. It gets set within `viewDidLoad` which you can see below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.tableViewPortrait) {
        self.tableView = self.tableViewPortrait;
    } else {
        self.tableView = self.tableViewLandscape;
    }

    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];

    if (![MXSAnnouncementManager sharedAnnouncementManager].latestAnnouncements) {
        [MXSAnnouncementManager loadModel:@"MXSAnnouncementGroupAllAnnouncements" withBlock:^(id model, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                self.arrayLatestAnnouncements = [MXSAnnouncementManager sharedAnnouncementManager].latestAnnouncements;
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            } else {
                // show some error msg
            }
        }];
    } else {
        self.arrayLatestAnnouncements = [MXSAnnouncementManager sharedAnnouncementManager].latestAnnouncements;
    }

    [self setupPullToRefresh];
}
```

Whenever I'm in the tab, one of the two orientation-specific `IBOutlets` is always active and has an address in memory while the other is `nil`. Whenever I rotate, the roles reverse -- whatever had an address in memory previously is now `nil` and the other has been initialized and allocated which is why I do what I did with the `tableView` property in the snippet above. Here is where caveat #2 comes into the picture and it's a doozy -- it has to do with the view lifecycle. Here's a practical example for clarity sake: Say I load the app up in Landscape orientation. When I do, my `tableViewLandscape` outlet has an address in memory and my `tableViewPortrait` outlet is `nil`. That's the expected and desired behavior. Now, when I rotate the app, the crazy stuff begins. Here's one place where I need clarity from all of you with regards to instances of `UIViewControllers` and what's normal vs. what's not so read the following VERY slowly and carefully.

Rotating the app immediately causes the opposite orientation scene (another INSTANCE of `MXSAnnouncementsViewController`???) to call its `viewDidLoad` method (in this example, we're in Landscape so the Portrait scene invokes that method). In that method, my local `tableView` property gets set to the currently active table view for that orientation (see snippet above). When that method finishes, the previous LANDSCAPE instance of `MXSAnnouncementsViewController` invokes its `viewWillDisappear` method which is then followed by the PORTRAIT instance's invocation of its `viewWillAppear` method which then lastly ends with the LANDSCAPE instance calling its `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` callback -- that's the order of operation that I'm seeing from the breakpoints. I really do hope you got all of that because my mind just blew up from it all.

If you're still with me at this point, thank you because we're finally at the home stretch. As the title of this post suggests, the problem I'm trying to solve is my app freezing on rotation. If you haven't noticed on the `viewDidLoad` snippet, the last instruction to get executed is the `setupPullToRefresh` method which is the following:

```
- (void)setupPullToRefresh
{
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
}
```

Since I already explained the whole view lifecycle order of operations on rotation earlier, to make a very long story short, if I comment out that last `setupPullToRefresh` instruction at the end of `viewDidLoad` for `MXSAnnouncementsViewController`, my app works fine. If I include that instruction, my app becomes totally unresponsive on the first rotation and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Not sure if I'm dealing with an edge case here or something. Any and all insights are welcome and THANK YOU SO MUCH for reading all of this!

Comment: What is the app doing while it hangs, the main thread?

Comment: I'm not a pro yet in the realm of iOS Development and Debugging but, I just tried using Instruments and it doesn't look like the main thread is doing anything. I do see something that says <Call stack limit reached> but I'm not sure what that means. I could definitely dig deeper with a little direction but, I'm as useful as a rock on the ground alone.

Comment: Sometimes there are clues when you pause the app with || and look at the stack of the main thread.  Unpauzing-pauzing-again a few times may give different stack results of course.

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach is probably to abandon your current design of having two separate controllers for portrait and landscape. On iOS, you should always relayout the views for the orientation you want to be in, not destroying and recreating everything. By trying to handle it by recreating everything, you're just going to get yourself in trouble I think.

You can use auto layout to do complex reorderings of views upon rotation if you know it well, but probably your best bet is to scrap your current code to do landscape, and write code to simply rearrange the views yourself upon rotating. You'll have far fewer issues down the road, and your code will be easier for others to understand and maintain as well.

When you remove that one bit of code, your app may appear to be working just fine, but there is probably something going on behind the scenes that isn't quite correct that could come back to bite you in the future. That's probably why adding the line of code breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to add it after rotation

  ```
  -(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
      [self setupPullToRefresh];
  }
  ```
- If that doesn't help, create UIRefreshControl only once and set it to the right table on rotation.
- If that doesn't help too, follow the first given answer (@Gavin's answer) and create only 1 table on viewDidLoad and relayout things in `-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`